# Get all fields defined in a bundle for a view mode

Tags: entities

Is it possible to get all the fields and field groups structures defined in a bundle for a view mode, in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to use the [`entity_get_display()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!entity.inc/function/entity_get_display/8) function.

It will return the entity view display, associated with the bundle and view mode you wanted. Simplest example:

```
$display = entity_get_display($entity_type, $bundle, $view_mode);
```